# How to solve broken routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working in a project that has a user to user friendship feature.
I don't know what is happening with my routes, but this is my output in html:

/friends.Friends -> this was supposed to be a link "friends", but when I click on it nothing happens

and

/friend_requests.Friend%20requests -> it was also supposed to be a link "friend_requests"

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "events#index"
  devise_for :users
  devise_scope :user do
    get "login", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "logout", :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    get "signup", :to => "devise/registrations#new"
  end
  resources :users, :only => [ :index, :show ]
  resources :friendships, :only => [:create, :update, :destroy]
  get '/friend_requests', to: 'friend_requests#index'
  get '/friends', to: 'friends#index'
  resources :events
end
```

and this is what i did in my view:

```
<%= link_to friends_path "Friends" %>
<br>
<%= link_to friend_requests_path "Friend requests" %>
```

This is the output of bundle exec rake routes

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                     root GET    /                                                                                        events#index
         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#new
             user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#create
     destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                devise/sessions#destroy
        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#new
       edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                           devise/passwords#edit
            user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                          PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                          POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#create
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                  devise/registrations#cancel
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                 devise/registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise/registrations#edit
        user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                          PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#destroy
                          POST   /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#create
                    login GET    /login(.:format)                                                                         devise/sessions#new
                   logout GET    /logout(.:format)                                                                        devise/sessions#destroy
                   signup GET    /signup(.:format)                                                                        devise/registrations#new
                    users GET    /users(.:format)                                                                         users#index
                     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                                                     users#show
              friendships POST   /friendships(.:format)                                                                   friendships#create
               friendship PATCH  /friendships/:id(.:format)                                                               friendships#update
                          PUT    /friendships/:id(.:format)                                                               friendships#update
                          DELETE /friendships/:id(.:format)                                                               friendships#destroy
          friend_requests GET    /friend_requests(.:format)                                                               friend_requests#index
                  friends GET    /friends(.:format)                                                                       friends#index
                   events GET    /events(.:format)                                                                        events#index
                          POST   /events(.:format)                                                                        events#create
                new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                                                                    events#new
               edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)                                                               events#edit
                    event GET    /events/:id(.:format)                                                                    events#show
                          PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)                                                                    events#update
                          PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                                                                    events#update
                          DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                                                                    events#destroy
                     page GET    /*id                                                                                     high_voltage/pages#show
       rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
       rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
     rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

When I acces by typing localhost:300/friends or localhost:300/friend_requests it works
but when I try to use link to, it's broken :/

Comment: What's the output of `bundle exec rake routes`?

Comment: Why is your label after your path?

Comment: I'll put it in the question, check it out

Comment: OOOOHH hahauahaahhaha! Thanks dude! I don't know what I was doing...
Now it's <%= link_to "Friends", friends_path %>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **The order of your arguments is not correct.**

From the [**Docs**](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

> link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block) public
>
> Creates an anchor element of the given name using a URL created by the set of options. See the valid options in the documentation for url_for. It’s also possible to pass a String instead of an options hash, which generates an anchor element that uses the value of the String as the href for the link. Using a :back Symbol instead of an options hash will generate a link to the referrer (a JavaScript back link will be used in place of a referrer if none exists). If nil is passed as the name the value of the link itself will become the name.

**The name should be passed as first argument but you are passing it as second.**

Try to swap the arguments like this:

```
<%= link_to "Friends" ,friends_path %>
<br>
<%= link_to "Friend requests", friend_requests_path %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your link_to helper in the view is not ok,

link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)

```
<%= link_to "Friends", friends_path %>
<br>
<%= link_to "Friend requests", friend_requests_path  %>
```